# Xamarin and native libs

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, cocoapods

I'm considering trying Xamarin instead of writing my apps in both Swift and Java. One big thing I wondering about though is third party libraries and open source libraries. Do I generally need to find C# libraries for this, or can I use native libraries for stuff I'm used to working with or can't find a similar C# library.

Like, could I use a Gradle dependency in a Xamarin Android app or a Cocoapod dependency in a Xamarin iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use native [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) libraries in Xamarin by creating binding projects for them.

Answer (score 3):

You can create binding project for iOS and Android libraries by yourself
But it has some limitation as well

such as Swift based project is not directly supported for binding in xamarin and there are some workarounds for that

Always check if the library that you are looking for is already available in [monotouch bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings) and then think about creating your own binding